# How can we create more than one Reducers using React-Redux Hooks API using useSelector() and useDispatch()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

If we make more than one reducers we combine it by using combineReducers but when the useSelector gets the state from which Reducers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the React-Redux [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector):

```
const result : any = useSelector(selector : Function, equalityFn? : Function)
```

> Allows you to extract data from the Redux store state, using a selector function

Just like `mapStateToProps` worked, the selector function receives the store state which is combined by all of your reducers.

So lets say you have a two reducers, one named `counterReducer` and the other `timeReducer` and you want data from one of them you'll do:

```
const counter = useSelector(state => state.counterReducer.data)
```

Or

```
const counter = useSelector({counterReducer} => counterReducer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks Matan, I didnot include .data in the end. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`useSelector` is passed your [entire Redux store state as its only argument](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector). So if you have two reducers, that are namespaced `foo` and `bar`

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({foo: fooReducer, bar: barReducer})
```

you could access them like this:

```
// state is your entire redux store
useSelector((state) => {
  console.log(state.foo);
  console.log(state.bar);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Galupuf. I got the states on my console, but how could I display it in the DOM?